# Current scope not available anymore in other div when same controller is used

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-scope

I have a view that is using a directive with isolated scope. Inside the directive the propery in scope is changed and this should do an action in the view.

Inside the div where my directive is used the scope property is changed correctly. But when I go outside of that div the scope property is not changed.

```
<div class="container-main with-actionbar">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" ng-if="rubricCompleted === false">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <div role="definition"><span ng-bind-html="description"></span></div>
            <question data-question="activeQuestion" disable-next-question="disableNextQuestion" />
            disable next button: {{disableNextQuestion}} -> FALSE (Correct value!!!)
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-if="rubricCompleted === true">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <wizard-result rubric-id="rubricId"></wizard-result>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
disable next button in other div: {{disableNextQuestion}} -> TRUE (value in scope is not known anymore)
</div>
```

This is my route for that part:

```
$stateProvider.state(
                        "overview",
                        {
                            url: "/overview",
                            templateUrl: "questionnaire_overview",
                            controller: "overviewController",
                            controllerAs: 'controller'
                        });
```

This is my directive:

```
module app.questionnaire.directives {
export class questionDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public templateUrl = 'questionnaire_question';
    public scope = {
        question: '=',
        disableNextQuestion: '='
    };
    public restrict = 'E';
    public controller = "questionController";
    public controllerAs = 'ctrl';
    public replace = true;

    constructor() {
    }

    public static create(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        var directive = () => new questionDirective();

        directive.$inject = [];

        return directive;
    }
}
}
```

What could be the reason that the scope property is not set correctly? How can I solve this?

Comment: what is disableNextQuestion and activeQuestion in your html?

Comment: The application is going about a question list that has to be filled in by a person. activeQuestion is the question that is currently active, this question needs to be filled in before it is possible to go to the next question. The disableNextQuestion property is set to false when the question is valid and it is possible to proceed.

Comment: Try to use an object with an dot in it like:

     `<question data-question="activeQuestion" disable-next-question="nextQuestion.disabled" />`

with

   `var nextQuestion = {
        disabled: true
    }`

Comment: After some more research I've found this blog post:
http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes
(look at pitfall #5)

This mentions wath kabaehr said.